# Winform SaveFileDialog Word

Tags: winforms, ms-word, savefiledialog

I need your help on SaveFileDialog

From code in the Temp folder a word file in which i insert data.
I then open the file in Word so it can be edited.

When tho Word document is closed i would like to have a popup th show which would ask where to save the file. That's why i'm using a SaveFileDialog popup.

Right now the SaveFileDialog just asks wether i want to save the changes to my file in the Temp folder or not, instead of asking where i want to save it as a new file.

When the document is closed i used

```
application.DocumentBeforeClose +=newApplicationEvents4_DocumentBeforeCloseEventHandler(application_DocumentBeforeClose);
```

In application_DocumentBeforeClose() i open a SaveFileDialog popup.

My goal would be to copy the file to the SaveFileDialog.FileName path and then delete the file in the Temp folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an easy way to force the "save as" dialog would be to open a template instead of a document...